# Gitlab Runner dosent know Docker Command

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

i have a Problem on my Gitlab Runner.
I try to make a Pipeline for my Company and i fails eveytime. I need to build and test an Dockerfile.
Everything is on Windows.
I run my Gitlab Runner in an Dockercontainer with an Shell executor.
This is my config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner-Docker"
  url = "companys gitlab"
  id = 30
  token = "mytoken"
  token_obtained_at = 
  token_expires_at =
  executor = "shell"
  privileged = true
```

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
docker-build:
  tags:
  - bnxt
  - go
  stage: build 
  image: gitlab/dind
  services: 
  - docker:18.09.7-dind
  script: 
     - docker build -t my-go-app -f Dockerfile
```

and this is the dockerfile i need to execute:

```
FROM bnxt-go-base-image:latest

#Sourcecode kopieren
COPY . ./

#Go-Anwendung bauen
RUN go build -o /app

#Go-Anwendung starten
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

and there is this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)
  on Runner-Docker ZvMv2Gkz1, system ID: r_wZMdbVPxMnte
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on 9361725fa8aa...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/ZvMv2Gkz1/0/it-edv/go-permission-service/.git/
Checking out 57f8366c as detached HEAD (ref is cicd_test)...
Skipping object checkout, Git LFS is not installed for this repository.
Consider installing it with 'git lfs install'.
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
$ docker build -t my-go-app -f Dockerfile
bash: line 128: docker: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

when i use this config with a docker-windows executor:

```
    concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner-Docker"
  url = ""
  id = 30
  token = ""
  token_obtained_at = 
  token_expires_at = 
  executor = "docker-windows"
   [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:dind" # You can also use "docker" here if you prefer the non-DinD image
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    network_mode = "host" # Use this if you want to access host network from within Docker-in-Docker
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

i get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)
  on Runner-Docker ZvMv2Gkz1, system ID: r_wZMdbVPxMnte
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor 00:09
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:826:0s)
```

please can someone help me i just dont know what to do anymore :(

i tried very much, like other executer (docker executor), ne .gitlab.ci.yml file and so on.
i tried really very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're using a shell executor, so you need `docker` installed on the runner. The `image:` and `services:` configurations don't do anything if you're using a shell executor. Alternatively, configure a docker executor and your job configuration should work.

Comment: Did you isntall docker?

Comment: i installed docker and i tried a docker-windows executor and the runner dosent even get over the preparation phase
i updatet the thread maybe with those new informations you can help me @sytech